How to Disable Filesystem Expansion on First Boot in Bookworm?
I want to prevent the filesystem from automatically expanding on the first boot. Simple methods used in previous versions of Raspbian seem to be no longer applicable from the boot partition.
Is there a simple recommended approach for Bookworm?

look for resize in filenames

@jsotola I think firstboot is the filename to look for :p
